# Why are my resources so low?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Whenever I enter Fallout Shelter, either my power or water levels are low, but when I check my stats it shows that my production for both is almost double or triple the consumption. If that's the case, how can they be so low?

Answer (score 3):

[Kadima is correct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/280135/108003). To elaborate:

Resource consumption continues for some time after you close the app. I don't know the exact time, but I've heard figures from a few minutes to more like twenty.

So, if you have enough resources not because you have a lot of production capacity, but because your cycle time is short, then you can run in to a problem. This is because you only have enough resources so long as you continue collecting them from the production rooms. Once you close the app, consumption continues, but production does not.

This can be solved with a Mr. Handy. He will continue collecting resources on the designated floor after you close the app.

Comment: I see, so if I designate Mr.Handy's to floors with production rooms, my production will continue along with my consumption?

Comment: @DevinGordon Yeah. Since you can now get Mr Handys as rewards for challenges, I had a vault with four Mr Handys. Every production room had one eventually. When I had just one, if I was ever starting to get low on a resource, I moved him to that room, and the next time I opened up the vault that resource bar was full. It still stops after a few minutes, but you'll be producing for those few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The app will actually keep recording resource usage after you close it for a short time. This is why resources tend to be low when you first load the app. You can solve this by having extra resource rooms and only closing the app when you are near 100% capacity. This way, the shelter won't be able to use up too much of your resources before it realizes you're not playing any more.